# Convert SVG to png or other?

Tags: python, svg, png, jupyter-notebook

Since it's very easy to display the content of a SVG file inside the iPython notebook, is there also a way (easy too) to get what we see inside a png file or other ?

```
from IPython.display import SVG
SVG(filename='../images/python_logo.svg')
```

If I do `svg = SVG(filename='../images/python_logo.svg')`

How can I save it to a png file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG are vectors images (the drawings are saved as commands to draw lines, circles, etc). PNGs are bitmaps. So to convert SVG to PNG, you need a renderer.

The most obvious solution is ImageMagick, a library you have already installed, as it is used in several programs. A less obvious approach is using Inkscape. Using the commandline options, it's possible to use Inkscape as a conversion program. As Inkscape is vector oriented, I suspect quality to be better than ImageMagick (which is more bitmap-minded).

As a vector image (SVG) is a text file containing drawing instructions, it's easier to understand. PNGs contain just pixel information, and, to make things worse, they are compressed with a fairly complicated algorithm. Making sense of them is not as easy.

Have a look at the [Inkscape man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inkscape), it's fairly obvious how to use it. [This is the IMagick convert help](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

Comment: The OP has a weird sense of 'easy' and 'difficult'. A bitmap is just a bitmap, while with SVG there are all kinds of possible problems: color interpretation, line width, scaling and transformation, antialiasing, local or embedded fonts ... If "just use a library!" is the "easy" answer for SVGs, that goes as well for PNGs. Possibly double so.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, but those things are mostly not in the SVG, but in the display of the SVG image on screen. SVG by itself isn't that complicated - at least it's one of the smaller w3c standards :-)

Comment: Never knew SVG are saved as instructions (Knew they were vector format but didn't think deeper) +1 for giving me knowledge :D