# How to covert svg, eps and ai to png in ghostscript

Tags: svg, converters, ghostscript, eps

I have to convert svg, eps and ai files to png for show thumbnails. Following command support for ai and eps, but not working for svg. Is there are any way to convert these file formats to png using same command.

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1440 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=960 -r300 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=outputfile.jpeg inputfile.eps
```

Comment: Use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) and its `convert` utility

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. "imagemagick" and "convert" use more memory and processor than ghostscript. When we convert multiple files "imagemagick" or "convert" cannot use

Comment: You could use some `for` loop in a shell script to run `convert` many times

Comment: BTW ghostscript is a PostScript interpreter. It is not intended to process SVG files. Please **edit your question** don't comment it. Do you need to use ghostscript for tasks it is not suited for, or do you need to convert `.svg` files to `.png` ones? It is not the same, and you should improve your question

Comment: It looks like you are asking the wrong question. It should be "what is the best way to convert SVG to PNG", but those questions are off-topic on SO, so you need to ask them elsewhere.

Comment: Your question is a typical example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and its `convert` utility or find some other [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) to [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) converter (perhaps [`inkscape`](http://inkscape.org/) used [with](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/man/inkscape-man.html) `--export-png=`*file* `--without-gui`), see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30302331/841108), or even spend a year studying SVG and PNG formats and writing your own converter.

[ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) is a [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) interpreter. It can handle `.eps` (this is for [Encapsulated PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript)) files because they are in some variant of PostScript. Since [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) is related to PostScript, you can ask `gs` to output PDF. But [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is completely unrelated to PostScript, so `gs` cannot process `.svg` files!

**You cannot use `gs` to convert SVG files.**

<sup>(Pedantically, PostScript is a [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) programming language and has [File](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Language.htm#File) IO primitives, so in theory you could spend several years writing *in PostScript* your own SVG to PNG converter and use `gs`to run it. You don't want to do that)</sup>

Comment: Can't we convert svg to pdf and pdf convert to png using "gs"

Comment: But how would you convert SVG to PDF? Probably using ImageMagick too!!

Comment: I do not think Ghostscript deals with SVG file. For that you need Inkscape or RSVG. But those probably do not output PDF, likely only raster format.

Comment: I did use `inkscape` to get a  `.pdf` output